# Excel VBA insert rows under the column if adjacent cell value matches column names

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have an `OrderForm` in sheet `OrderForm`, and a table `OrderTable` in Sheet `OrderData` that looks like this:
[image]

Now the maximum product number that one customerID can submit in one form is 3, and the list comes from the data validation from the the `productlist`.

My goal is that everytime an `OrderForm` is submitted, then the record is automatically added as a new row in the `OrderTable`.

Now the problem is, how do I get the amount entered for that order be stored in the column where the column name matches the product entered in M9:M11?

So for example, if this customer ID is 151A, and he or she ordered Blueberry= 15, Apple= 20, and Plum=5, then I would want these amounts to be stored int eh `OrderTable` as a new record for customer 151A, with the amounts under the matching column names correspondingly.

This is my code that I currently try, but I can't figure out the match-lookup part:

```
Sub Submit_OrderForm()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("OrderData")

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

customerid = Sheets("OrderForm").Range("N6").Value

  'This is where I'm stuck. If column header matches the product chosen, Then:
    ws.Range("C:H").Value = Worksheets("OrderForm").Range("N9").Value  'Product 1
    ws.Range("C:H").Value = Worksheets("OrderForm").Range("N10").Value   'Product 2
    ws.Range("C:H").Value = Worksheets("OrderForm").Range("N11").Value  'Product 3
    End If

End Sub
```

Anyone knows how to deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Every order should be in a new row even if it's from the same customer? Do you need them to be sorted for customers?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter if its the same customer ID. Every order creates a new row

Comment: Just a advise, you can use the headers of the OrderTable as data validation for the order form products, this way you won't have to maintain twice the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will achieve your expected results, it will use the .Find method to match the columns with the products entered then use them columns to add the values:

```
Sub Submit_OrderForm()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("OrderData")
Dim wsOrderForm As Worksheet: Set wsOrderForm = Worksheets("OrderForm")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

Set Product1 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M9").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
'find the column that matches the first product
Set Product2 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M10").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set Product3 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M11").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

ws.Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = wsOrderForm.Range("N6").Value
ws.Cells(LastRow, Product1.Column).Value = wsOrderForm.Range("N9").Value
ws.Cells(LastRow, Product2.Column).Value = wsOrderForm.Range("N10").Value
ws.Cells(LastRow, Product3.Column).Value = wsOrderForm.Range("N11").Value
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the same customers to be added into a single row, the following will achieve that:

```
Sub Submit_OrderForm()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("OrderData")
Dim wsOrderForm As Worksheet: Set wsOrderForm = Worksheets("OrderForm")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

customerid = wsOrderForm.Range("N6").Value

Set customerfound = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=customerid, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set Product1 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M9").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set Product2 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M10").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set Product3 = ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=wsOrderForm.Range("M11").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not customerfound Is Nothing Then
    ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product1.Column).Value = ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product1.Column).Value + wsOrderForm.Range("N9").Value
    ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product2.Column).Value = ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product1.Column).Value + wsOrderForm.Range("N10").Value
    ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product3.Column).Value = ws.Cells(customerfound.Row, Product1.Column).Value + wsOrderForm.Range("N11").Value
Else
    ws.Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = customerid
    ws.Cells(LastRow, Product1.Column).Value = ws.Range("N9").Value
    ws.Cells(LastRow, Product2.Column).Value = ws.Range("N10").Value
    ws.Cells(LastRow, Product3.Column).Value = ws.Range("N11").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is excellent! Thanks Xabier for your answer, you're really a lifesaver :) , anyway, I thank you too for the bonus solution, even your first answer already gives what I need now. A million thanks again! :))

Comment: @user71812 glad to be of assistance. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Find()` method of `Range` object and loop through actual product input:

```
Sub Submit_OrderForm()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim customerID As Variant

    Set ws = Worksheets("OrderData")

    With Worksheets("OrderForm")
        customerID = .Range("N6").Value
        If IsEmpty(customerID) Then Exit Sub ' exit if no customer input
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("M9:M11")) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' exit if no products input

        lastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'finds the last blank row in OrderData data

        ws.Cells(lastRow, 2).Value = customerID ' write customer Id
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In .Range("M9:M11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through products actual input
            ws.Cells(lastRow, ws.Range("C4:H4").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column) = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a formula for the row to get the data, then overwrite it with the value.

I also suggest you name your ranges, to make it easier to retrieve the values.

```
Sub Submit_OrderForm()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, os as Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set os = WorkSheets("OrderForm")
    Set ws = Worksheets("OrderData")
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the next blank row

    ws.Range(LastRow, "B").Value = os.Range("N6")
    With ws.Range(LastRow, "C").Resize(,6)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C4,'OrderData'!$M$9:$N$11,2,FALSE),"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    end with
End Sub
```